# In tensorflow, how do you create a graph that adds more than two arguments?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In tensorflow, I want to do something like:

```
A = tf.add(a, b, c)
```

That is, I want to create a graph that adds more than two arguments. How do I do this?

Comment: what is the aim of this procedure?

Comment: Alternatively `tf.add(a, b)`, `tf.add(a, c)`, `tf.add(b, c)` ?

Comment: @Cut7er Of course I can add a and b, and then add a+b and c, but I just want to make the code neater.

Comment: Have no idea how it works, so maybe the better idea would be to check in the docs. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/add_n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Use [`tf.accumulate_n`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/accumulate_n).

#### More on that

The answer is actually more complicated in tensorflow than one would anticipate.

You can chain the additions:

```
res = a + b + c
```

but then you create as many nodes as there are additions. What's more, you force the order of the additions: `a` and `b` are summed first (so TF has to wait for their values to be ready) then `c` is added.

The solution seems to be

```
res = tf.add_n([a, b, c])
```

which creates a single node. Alas, `tf.add_n` is not efficient. It waits for all inputs to be ready before summing them, so it is actually less efficient than chaining additions, which can start as soon as `a` and `b` are ready. Second, all inputs must be in memory at the same time, which wastes memory — again, when chaining additions, `a` and `b` can be discarded before summing `c`.

The better way to sum multiple inputs is to use `tf.accumulate_n`, which alleviates the problems of `tf.add_n`, because it sums inputs as they come.

IMHO the only reason for still having `tf.add_n` around is for compatibility with TF < 1.7, for which `tf.accumulate_n` does not pass gradients through — a major con if you intend to support older version of TF.